# Iron Router - Conditional routes depending on tenant

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm working on a multi-tenant application and I'm unsure how to load routes conditionally.

I had:

```
   var tenant = resolveTenant();
   if (tenant === null) {

        Router.configure({
            layoutTemplate: 'main',
            notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
        })
        Router.route('home', {
            path: '/'
        })

        Router.route('newClient', {
            path: 'signup'
        })
    } else {
        Router.configure({
            layoutTemplate: 'storeMain',
            notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
        })
        Router.route('storeHome', {
            path: '/'
        })
    }
```

So if a tenant couldn't be resolved, load the main site.

This worked just fine, not pretty, but fine. However the issue is when a tenant doesn't exist.

Case:

- http://localhost/ - Load main
- http://store1.localhost/ - Load store
- http://notastore.localhost/ - Load notTenant template.

In order to do this I need to do a call to the database. So I wrapped the conditions inside a method call with a callback:

```
    Router.configure({
        layoutTemplate: "loading"
    });
    var tenant = resolveTenant();
    Meteor.call("tenant.exists", tenant, function(err, exists) {
        if (tenant !== null && !exists) {
            Router.configure({
                layoutTemplate: 'noTenant'
            })
            Router.route('noTenant', {
                path: '/'
            })
        } else if (tenant === null) {

            Router.configure({
                layoutTemplate: 'main',
                notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
            })
            Router.route('home', {
                path: '/'
            })

            Router.route('newClient', {
                path: 'signup'
            })
        } else {
            Router.configure({
                layoutTemplate: 'storeMain',
                notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
            })
            Router.route('storeHome', {
                path: '/'
            })
        }
    })
```

The problem is, is it won't move from the loading template configuration  after the call has completed. And if I remove the loading template route, I get the iron router landing page.

For completion, here is the "tenant.exists" method:

```
  "tenant.exists": function(url){
    if(url === null){
      return false
    }
    return Tenants.find({"url": url}).count() > 0;
  },
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**Edit**

I did try to remove the conditions from the method call and running the query on the client-side. However the count always returned 0 when it shouldn't.

```
 if (tenant !== null && Tenants.find({"url": tenant}).count() === 0) {
      Router.configure({
          layoutTemplate: 'noTenant'
      })
      Router.route('noTenant', {
          path: '/'
      })
  } else if (tenant === null) {

      Router.configure({
          layoutTemplate: 'main',
          notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
      })
      Router.route('home', {
          path: '/'
      })

      Router.route('newClient', {
          path: 'signup'
      })
  } else {
      Router.configure({
          layoutTemplate: 'storeMain',
          notFoundTemplate: 'not-found'
      })
      Router.route('storeHome', {
          path: '/'
      })
  }
```

Comment: I have the impression that there might be some problem in the method call.. were you able to debug and see if the method call is responding as you expect?

Comment: Yes everything is as expected, returns true if exists, false if not. I did try to remove the conditions from the method call and did `Tenants.find({"url": tenant}).count() === 0` but the call kept returning true (as in no tenant found with that URL), any ideas on why that would be? I haven't been doing Meteor for too long.

Comment: If you are doing the query on the client side, is the entire Tenants collection published there? Just try to query the collection in the browser console and check what is publish there: Tenants.find().fetch();

Comment: I'm getting an empty array. :\

Comment: Ok, so this tells you that you need to work on the subscription first. once you make the collection available on the client side, you shoudl get the result you expect. Anyways, you may think if this is really what you want - publish all Tenants to the client. Maybe you could do it as a test, validate your code, then migrate it back to the server side. Try installing auto-publish package for testing purpose, and validate your code works.

Comment: Thanks for you help @RicardoPesciotta, you were right. I didn't publish the entire collection to the client, I added a publication with a parameter and used FlowRouter instead of Iron Router for the ability to wait and initialize. See my comment on Michel's answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please allow me to suggest a much simpler approach that also lets you avoid publishing the names of all you tenants to every client while also avoiding the asynchronous side-effects of `Meteor.call()`:

1. Subscribe to a tenant subscription passing the tenant name as a parameter
2. In the corresponding publication, just return the one matching tenant
3. In an `onBeforeAction` handler, see if there's a tenant record at all and proceed if so, otherwise render the appropriate page.

Router:

```
var tenant = resolveTenant();

Router.route('/',{
  name: 'storeHome',
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    if ( Tenants.findOne() ) this.next();
    else if ( tenant ) this.render('noTenant');
    else this.render('signup');
  },
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('tenant', tenant);
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('tenant',name,function(){
  check(name,String);
  return Tenants.find({ url: tenant });
});
```

Taken from patterns [here](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html).

Comment: Good answer Michel. I'll consider implemented this. I did get mine working with the Meteor.call in the end. I went with FlowRouter for `FlowRouter.wait()` and `FlowRouter.initialize()` when the call has completed. Yours is a much tidier solution however and would solve my issue as outlined in my question. So I'll mark this as the answer.